# Drupal 10, Taxonomy term View:

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

'Fields: Taxonomy term revision: Revision user' simply doesn't work.
Similar field in Content View works as expected.
There are even empty markup (Inscpector: [FF Inspector SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb4Lv.png)
Am I doing something wrong?

Drupal 10 Taxonomy term View don't work as expected, user is not shown